# Passing arrays into functions, file.exe stopped working

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I wrote a program to take a two dimensional array as input and find the sum of the individual columns.

And when I compiled the program I got no errors, but once I run it, I get a dialogue box saying `untitled5.exe stopped working` where `untitled5` is the file name.

I got this error quite a few times. I have used both dev C++ and codeblocks to compile my program, so what is the reason for this?

Is this a problem with my code or with my compiler or with my laptop?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void summation(int arr[][5], int size);
int main() {
  int n, arr[n][5], sum, i, j;
  printf("enter the number of rows");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      printf("%d,%d th element is", i, j);
      scanf("%d", & arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
  summation(arr, 5);
  return 0;
}
void summation(int arr[][5], int size) {
  int i, j, s = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      s = s + arr[i][j];
    }
    printf("%d", s);
  }

}
```

Comment: n is not initialized before the array definition that's why

Answer (score 0):

In `main()` you are using `i` to index the first dimension of the array.  In `summation()` you are using `i` to index the second dimension of the array.  I think that you are going beyond the end of the first dimension inside `summation()` when `main()` does not fill up that much of the array (e.g., when you enter 2 for the number of rows).

I think you want

```
summation (arr,5);
```

And, inside `summation()`:

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   s=s+arr[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void summation (int arr[][5], int size, int rows);
int main()
{
    int n, sum, i, j;
    printf("enter the number of rows");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n][5];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("%d,%d th element is",i,j);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
    }
    }
    summation (arr, 5, n);
    return 0;
}
void summation (int arr[][5], int size, int rows)
{
    int i,j,s=0;
    for(i=0;i<rows;j++)
    {

        for (j=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            s=s+arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d",s);    
}
```

So first off I moved your array declaration to after you have initialized n and made it equal to something.

Then your next problem was you were probably going out of bounds in your summation function. You always have 5 columns in your 2darray, but you can have a different amount of rows. Pass the amount of rows, n, into the function summation to make sure you don't go out of bounds.